# Discovering if any element has any class in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, class, loops

I have inherited some jQuery and HTML and need to find out if any of the HTML elements have a class name of any value. I've read around a few threads and Googled but can't find anything useful.
So in pseudo-code what I'd like is:

```
Loop through all HTML elements

If any of them have any class at all:
    Get their class name as a string
```

Hoping that makes sense!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try:

```
$('*').each(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass()) {
        var class_name = $(this).attr('class');
        // do something
    }
});
```

Why you would want to do this, I have no idea. It is **very** inefficient

Comment: Yeah, it's a pretty heavy operation. I'd bet that there's a better approach to the problem.

Comment: Thank you :) its not something I want to do particularly. I'm no jQuery expert, but with the code I've inherited I think its maybe the only way to do what I need and the client (who fancies himself a talented amateur coder) wants.

I have managed to strip the number of classes down to 6 so I'm hoping that will reduce overhead.

Thanks again, I appreciate it.

Comment: reasonably efficient if $('*') selector is other than ' * '

Answer (score 13):

For what it's worth:

```
$(this).hasClass()
```

always returns *false*.

```
$("[class]")
```

doesn't work either, as it returns elements like

```
<p class=""> my p </p>
```

jsfiddle for both here: http://jsfiddle.net/JZ8LV/1/

**Solution**:

```
$(this).hasClass('')
```

returns *true* for elements *without* a class, including those of the form

```
<p class=""> my p </p>
```

so

```
$('*').each(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('') === false) {
        $("body").append($(this).prop("tagName") + " has a proper class defined <br/>");
    }
});
```

**returns all the tags with a proper class defined**.

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2Rtj5/

Comment: Man. You are great.

Answer (score 6):

You can use something like this:

```
$("[class]").each(function(){
   var className = $(this).attr("class");
})
```

[Has Attribute Selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/)

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/L5WAV/1/  (see results in console - two divs should be found)

Comment: Thank you too for your time, I appreciate it :)

Answer (score 2):

To get all elements with class you can use `$('*[class]')`:

```
$('*[class]').each(function(){
    // do what you want
});
```

You can even easily count them with `$('*[class]').length`.

Comment: Thanks for your time also, I do appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var classObj = {};

$('*').each(function(){
    var cNames = this.className.split(' ');
    for(var i=0, l=cNames.length; i<l; i+=1){
        classObj[cNames[i]] = true;
    }
});
```

That would give you an Object (`classObj`) with every appearing class of the document as property, so a class name won't show up multiple times if there are elements with the same class in the document. I really would not do this or see any use-case in this though.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct question, but I needed it, so here it goes for future users.

In case you want to find if *any* element has a *specific* class, you could use this function:

```
function find_any_element(className) {
    var found = false;
    $('*').each(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass(className)) {
            var class_name = $(this).attr('class');
            alert("There is an element with this class: " + class_name);
            found = true;
        }
    });
    if(!found) {
        alert("No element with className '" + className + "' found.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to loop over your elements:

```
if( jQuery( ".myClass" ).is( ":visible" ) )
{
    // do your thing
}
```

The downside is that your element cannot have the `display`-property set to `none`